# Deserialization message contract first grpc approach

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

In the grpc contract first approach is there any way to convert into custom C# object from autogenerated c# object from the proto message.

Type to deserialize

```
class HelloRep
{
   string message { get; set; }
}
```

proto message

```
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Client code

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");            
var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
var reply =  client.SayHello(new HelloRequest { Name = "xx" });
```

Searching for a method to convert reply into HelloRep.

ex :  `HelloRep hello = Serializer.Deserialize<HelloRep>(reply);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm less familiar with C#. In other languages (Golang, Python etc.), `protoc` generates additional fields|methods that preclude automatic conversion.

Using custom classes, you get flexibility of field|method naming and type conversions if you want them.

Comment: Thanks, DazWilkin for the answer, yes even in c# it has a compiler that generates .cs file automatically. what i m looking for a way to customize or not to use this autogenerated class, instead use my own class

Comment: Every language-binding has some form of struct|class generation to represent the service|messages in the language. If you want to use the language-specific methods e.g. `Marshall`, `Unmarshal` and shipping messages across the network, you must use these generated classes or something very similar to them.

Comment: Per your question, if you want to have your own representation of these classes to use in your code, you must write them yourself. This is also recommended; that you not use the generated classes|structs in your code directly. If you do, next time you change your protos or upgrade `protoc`, the generated classes could change even subtly and break your code. So, abstract the proto classes but you must write them for yourself.